# jquery onchange impacted by post event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, onchange

I am creating a store where products are listed with options (ie different sizes via a drop down and different fabrics via a selection of radio buttons).  (Check out www.searing.me/newstore)

I wrote the following code so that if a selection was made, the price would be updated without needing a POST to do so and thus refreshing to the top of the screen.  My problem is - that when I "add to cart" then ALL prices are getting updated with the price that was initially selected.

So, in essence, on the first product, if you select the "brown chord" option to add $2.25 - the price changes by adding $2.25 to $30.00 - thus $32.25.  HOWEVER, when you click add to cart - the product to the right changed ITS price by $2.25 as well.

I assume this has something to do with the POST registering another onchange event for each....I don't know.  And I'm VERY MUCH a beginner with Jquery/Javascript to really know what's happening.

Script is:

```
function updatePrice(e) {
    var product = $(e.target).closest('.product');
    var price = parseFloat(product.data('price'));

    var sizePrice = parseFloat(product.find('[name=sizeSelect] :selected').data('price'));
    if (isNaN(sizePrice)) {
        sizePrice = 0;
    }

    var patternPrice = parseFloat(product.find('[name=fabric]:checked').data('price'));
    if (isNaN(patternPrice)) {
    patternPrice = 0;
    }

    var totalPrice = price + sizePrice + patternPrice;
    product.find('.totalCost').text('$' + totalPrice.toFixed(2));

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '.product', updatePrice);
}
```

What do I need to do so as to prevent all the other products updating their price on the add to cart?

EDIT:  First, Important to note that the script runs perfect up to the point that the submit button is clicked.  Once the button is clicked, that is what updates ALL the prices.

Here's the page script:

```
<?php

    echo "<div><img style='padding-left:35px; float:left;' src='/images/just11stitchesbannerII.png'></div>";
    echo "<div style='float:right; padding-right:55px;'>";
    echo return_categories($dbConnection);
    echo "</div>";

    if ($cart->countItems() > 0) {
        echo '<div style="float:right; clear:left; padding-right:50px;">
                <a style="outline:0;" class="gallery2" href="shoppingcartdev.php"><img style="width:55px; padding-left:75px;" src="/images/scart.png"></img></a><br/>
                <span style="font-size:.75em;">You have ' . $cart->countItems() . ' item(s) in your shopping cart.</span>
            </div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<div style="float:right; clear:left; padding-right:50px;">
                <img style="width:55px; padding-left:75px;" src="/images/scart.png"></img><br/>
                <span style="font-size:.75em;">You have ' . $cart->countItems() . ' in your shopping cart.</span>
            </div>';
    }
    echo '<h1 style="clear:left; padding-top:5px;">Products</h1>';

    // Find out if page is displaying all the products or if it is being filtered
    $testProducts = new Products();

    if (isset($_POST['category_submit']) && isset($_POST['categories'])) {
        $_POST['test'] = 'FALSE';
        $linkArray = printFilteredProductLinks("/newstore", $dbConnection->db, $_POST['categories']);
        $myarray = $testProducts->getSelectedOrderProducts($linkArray["order_by"], $linkArray["start"], $linkArray["display"], 1, $_POST['categories']);
    }
    else {
        $_POST['test'] = 'FALSE';
        $linkArray = printProductLinks("/newstore", $dbConnection->db, 1);
        $myarray = $testProducts->getOrderProducts($linkArray["order_by"], $linkArray["start"], $linkArray["display"], 1);
    }

    $counter = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $flag = 0;                         // used to check if at end of table and only 1 cell for that row
    $stepthroughitemcount =0;
    $itemcount = count($myarray);

    if ($itemcount % 2 == 1) {
        $counter = floor( $itemcount / 2 );     // If Flag = 1 then there will be one more cell to make in the final row.
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        $counter = $itemcount / 2;
    }

    // START TABLE



    echo "<table style='margin:5px; border-spacing:5px;'>";


    while ($i < $counter) {
        $tdcount = 0;

        while ($tdcount < 2) {
            $optionCount = 0;
            $mySizes = new Sizes($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getID()); 
            $myPatterns = new Patterns($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getID());   


            echo    "<td valign='top'  class='product' data-price='" . returnTotalPrice($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPrice()) . "' style='width:575px; padding-top:8px; border: 2px solid green; padding:8px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ACBF9A;'>
                            <div style='width:175px; float:left; text-align:center;'>
                                <a style='display:inline; float:none;' class='gallery' href='/prod_pics/" . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPictureName() . "'><img id='picture' src='/red_prod_pics/" . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPictureName() . "'</img></a>
                                <p class='totalCost' style='text-align:center; margin-top:0px;'>$" . number_format(returnTotalPrice($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPrice()), 2) . "</p>
                                <form id='productForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='newstore.php' method='POST'>

                                <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{$myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getID()}' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='{$myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPrice()}' />
                                <p style='font-size:.7em; border:1px solid #008000; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ddf0dd; padding:2px;'>" . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDescription() . "</p>
                                <input style='display:inline; margin-top:5px; float:none;' type='submit' name='AddCart'  value='Add To Cart'/>
                            </div>
                            <div style='margin-left:10px; float:left; width:373px;'>
                                <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Sizes:</span>
                                <span style='padding-left:100px;'>
                                    <select  name='sizeSelect' style='width:200px; text-align:right;'>";
            if (isset($_POST['AddCart'])){
                foreach ($mySizes->getAllSizes() as $value) {
                    //echo "<option>valuesid = " . $value->getSID() . " postsizeselect = " . $_POST['sizeSelect'] . "</option>";
                    echo            "<option " . ( $value->getPSID() == $_POST['sizeSelect'] ? 'selected' : '') . " data-price='" . $value->getSPRICE()  . "' value=" . $value->getPSID() . ">" . $value->getSNAME() . "&emsp; $" . number_format($value->getSPRICE(), 2) . "</option>";
                }   
            }
            else {
                foreach ($mySizes->getAllSizes() as $value) {
                    //echo $value->getSID() . ' ' . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDefaultSize();
                    echo            "<option " . ( $value->getSID() == $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDefaultSize() ? 'selected' : '') . " data-price='" . $value->getSPRICE()  . "' value=" . $value->getPSID() . ">" . $value->getSNAME() . "&emsp; $" . number_format($value->getSPRICE(), 2) . "</option>";
                }
            }
            echo                    "</select>
                                </span>
                                <br/>
                                <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Fabrics & Colors:</span><br/>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>";
            $rowcount = 0;

            foreach ($myPatterns->getAllPatterns() as $value2)  {   
                if ($rowcount % 4 == 0) {
                    echo            '</tr>
                                    <tr>';
                }
                echo                    '<td style="float:left; width:85px; text-align:center; ">
                                            <img src="/patterns/' . $value2->getPATPICTURENAME() . '" /><br/>
                                            <span style="font-size:.65em; width:65px; color: #132301;">' . $value2->getPATNAME() . '</span><br/>
                                            <span>$' . number_format($value2->getPATPRICE(), 2) . '</span><br/>
                                            <input data-price="' . $value2->getPATPRICE() . '" type="radio" ' . ( $value2->getPATID() == $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDefaultFabric() ? "checked=\'checked\'" : "") . ' name="fabric" value=' . $value2->getPPID() . ' />
                                        </td>'; 
                $rowcount +=1;
            }
            echo                    '</tr>
                                </table>
                            </div></form>
                    </td>';
            $stepthroughitemcount +=1;
            $tdcount +=1;
        }


        echo "</tr>";
        $i+=1;

    }
    if ($flag == 1 ) {
        $mySizes = new Sizes($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getID()); 
        $myPatterns = new Patterns($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getID());   
            echo    "<tr>
                        <td valign='top' class='product' data-price='" . returnTotalPrice($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPrice()) . "' style='width:575px; padding-top:8px; border: 2px solid green; padding:8px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ACBF9A;'>
                            <div style='width:175px; float:left; text-align:center;'>
                                <a style='display:inline; float:none;' class='gallery' href='/prod_pics/" . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPictureName() . "'><img id='picture' src='/red_prod_pics/" . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPictureName() . "'</img></a>
                                <p class='totalCost' style='text-align:center; margin-top:0px;'>$" . number_format(returnTotalPrice($myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPrice()), 2) . "</p>
                                <form id='productForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='newstore.php' method='POST'>
                                <input style='display:inline;  float:none;' type='submit' name='AddCart'  value='Add To Cart'/>
                                <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{$myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getID()}' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='{$myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getPrice()}' />
                            </div>
                            <div style='margin-left:10px; float:left; width:373px;'>
                                <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Sizes:</span>
                                <span style='padding-left:100px;'>
                                    <select  name='sizeSelect' style='width:200px; text-align:right;'>";
            foreach ($mySizes->getAllSizes() as $value) {
                //echo $value->getSID() . ' ' . $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDefaultSize();
                echo                    "<option " . ( $value->getSID() == $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDefaultSize() ? 'selected' : '') . " data-price='" . $value->getSPRICE()  . "' value=" . $value->getPSID() . ">" . $value->getSNAME() . "&emsp; $" . number_format($value->getSPRICE(), 2) . "</option>";
            }                           
            echo                    "</select>
                                </span>
                                <br/>
                                <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Fabrics & Colors:</span><br/>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>";
            $rowcount = 0;

            foreach ($myPatterns->getAllPatterns() as $value2)  {   
                if ($rowcount % 4 == 0) {
                    echo            '</tr>
                                    <tr>';
                }
                echo                    '<td style="float:left; width:85px; text-align:center; ">
                                            <img src="/patterns/' . $value2->getPATPICTURENAME() . '" /><br/>
                                            <span style="font-size:.75em">' . $value2->getPATNAME() . '</span><br/>
                                            <span>$' . number_format($value2->getPATPRICE(), 2) . '</span><br/>
                                            <input data-price="' . $value2->getPATPRICE() . '" type="radio" ' . ( $value2->getPATID() == $myarray[$stepthroughitemcount]->getDefaultFabric() ? "checked=\'checked\'" : "") . ' name="fabric" value=' . $value2->getPPID() . ' />
                                        </td>'; 
                $rowcount +=1;
            }
            echo                    '</tr>
                                </table>
                            </div></form>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";

    if (isset($_POST['category_submit']) && isset($_POST['categories'])) {
        printFilteredProductLinks("/newstore", $dbConnection->db, $_POST['categories']);
    }
    else {
        printProductLinks("/newstore", $dbConnection->db, 1);
    }
    echo '</body>
        </html>';

?>
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. What is the html structure of your products?

Comment: SOMEHOW the submit / post is triggering the onchange event.  I changed the button to type button and then wrote this:  $('input[type=button]').click(function(){$('form').submit();});  and when I clicked on the button - it updated all the pricing again.

SOMEHOW - I need to figure a way to disable the on change event handler from triggering if page is submitted....

Comment: Ok - I think TravJenkins is correct - I believe that I have a SESSION variable holding my option prices and it's using that to update all the prices - let me play around and update here in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right and the event is triggered again.

I guess this happens because all your submit buttons have the same ID and the updatePrice function is called for each article.

Just give it a try and remove the id of the submit buttons.

Comment: I removed the id of the submit buttons and it still updates the price of all products.

Comment: I browsed your html code again and there are more elements with the same id (e.g. the form itself). Element IDs should be unique within the entire document. Thats what classes are for. Even it wont solve your actual problem, it may will but I cant test it, you should always use ids as unique selector.

Comment: I appreciate the comments.  Honestly, this is my very first PHP attempt.  Well, second if you count this as version 2 of the site.  Originally I had it set up so that each product was on a separate line with now options.  When my wife started listing pictures more than once so tat she could list several sizes, I realized I needed to revisit.

Honestly, I think I often get the id and name attribute mixed when I'm writing the code (before I get to the event tie-ins.  That, or I'm simply not following best practice if I'm using for CSS - I agree. But I honestly don't think the ID is the issue :(

Comment: hyde - just fyi I think I went in and removed the ID's.  Not sure why I had them to be honest - other than perhaps in trying out some js at some point.  It still doesn't work - but I am up to trying anything and really do appreciate your time.  Thank you.

Comment: SOMEHOW the submit / post is triggering the onchange event. I changed the button to type button and then wrote this: $('input[type=button]').click(function(){$('form').submit();}); and when I clicked on the button - it updated all the pricing again. SOMEHOW - I need to figure a way to disable the on change event handler from triggering if page is submitted..

Comment: Maybe an ajax submit is what will solve your problem. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. I'll post you an answer submitting your form with ajax soon.

Comment: I've visited the link you posted in your opening post, got it working now? If so, please provide your solution to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to select only the first result with

```
$.first();
```

Comment: `.closest()` should return just one result.

Comment: So - important to note - the code works fine prior to the page submit.  It ONLY updates the one price.  It's the submit (add to cart) that updates them all at one time.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this has to do with the post causing another onChange event... probably has to do with something on the "back end".

If you put a break point on the onChange code it only fires when you are changing the inputs (like you would expect). Also, when you get the page back after adding to cart the PHP is sending back HTML with the values already updated. Another important note - it is not just updating the one to the right it is updating the cost of ALL items in the shop.

Comment: you're right - sorry - it updates them all - I was just trying to point out the one on the right as an example - thanks for catchign that.

Comment: It also gets reset if you submit one of the forms that don't have any extra options. This also makes me thing it isn't the onChange (because that event would never be fired for those).

Comment: Trav - I believe you may be correct - I'm going to play around with some code and report back.